# git' is not recognized while using c# (web application)

Tags: c#, git, powershell

I want to execute the power shell logic using c#(web application) but i'm getting the issue

> The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I have added the git path in environmental variables and able to execute the same powershell logic from powershell window without any issues.

My powershell script:

```
function CheckoutTheCode($checkoutRepoUrl, $checkoutDirectory, $checkoutBranch)
{
    [hashtable]$Return = @{}
    try
    {
        # Cloning
        git clone --single-branch -b $checkoutBranch $checkoutRepoUrl $checkoutDirectory

        $Return.Status = $true
        $Return.Message = "Success"
    }
    catch
    {
        $Return.Message = $Error[0].Exception
        $Return.Status = $false
    }

    Return $Return 
}

$checkoutDirectory = "local directory for checkout"
$checkoutRepoUrl = "bit bucket repo url"
$checkoutBranch = "branch version"
CheckoutTheCode $checkoutRepoUrl $checkoutDirectory $checkoutBranch
```

My c# code:

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("PowerShell script");
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: To clarify: you added a system environment variable, right? And the user the web app runs as has access to the folder git resides in, right?

Comment: Yes, I have added system environment variable. Yes the user with which the app runs have access to the folder in which git resides in.

Comment: You are correct, but you also need to check if the user IIS / IIS Express is running under has access to that folder.

Comment: Sorry at first i have misunderstood your confirmation question.  Yes, I have added system environment variable. Yes the user with which the app runs have access to the folder in which git resides in.

Comment: And you've rebooted since you added the environment variable? (I assume you have, since it works for you when you run it manually, but to cover all bases I ask...)

Comment: No i didn't rebooted the system but it is working fine When i'm executing the script from power shell window. I have problem only when i'm executing through c# code.

Comment: Beyond that I'm not sure I'm afraid. Hopefully someone else will have a good suggestion :)

Comment: Thank you very much John for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In My case the issue is I have added the **system environment variable** after the c# web application is opened in visual studio.

When i have closed the visual studio and opened again, it's working fine.

Comment: Typical Visual Studio.